# In DX12 what Ordering Guarantees do multiple ExecuteCommandLists calls provide?

Tags: directx-12

Assuming a single threaded application. If you call `ExecuteCommandLists` twice (**A** and **B**). Is **A** guaranteed to execute all of its commands on the GPU before starting any of the commands from **B**? The closest thing I can find in the documentation is this, but it doesn't really seem to guarantee **A** finishes before **B** starts:

> Applications can submit command lists to any command queue from multiple threads. The runtime will perform the work of serializing these requests in the order of submission.

As a point of comparison, I know that this is explicitly **not** guarenteed in Vulkan:

> vkQueueSubmit is a queue submission command, with each batch defined by an element of pSubmits as an instance of the VkSubmitInfo structure. Batches begin execution in the order they appear in pSubmits, **but may complete out of order.**

However, I'm not sure if DX12 works the same way.

[Frank Luna's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1942270062) says:

> The command lists are executed in order starting with the first array element

However in that context he's talking about calling `ExecuteCommandLists` once with two command lists (**C** and **D**). Do these operate the same as two individual calls? My colleague argues that this still only guarantees that they are started in order, not that **C** finishes before **D** starts.

Is there more clear documentation somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Direct X forums, here's an answer from Microsoft engineer Jesse Natalie:

> Calling ExecuteCommandLists twice guarantees that the first workload
>   (A) finishes before the second workload (B). Calling
>   ExecuteCommandLists with two command lists allows the driver to merge
>   the two command lists such that the second command list (D) may begin
>   executing work before all work from the first (C) has finished.
>
> Specifically, the application is allowed to insert a fence signal or
>   wait between A and B, and the driver has no visibility into this, so
>   the driver must ensure that everything in A is complete before the
>   fence operation. There is no such opportunity in a single call to the
>   API, so the driver can optimize that scenario.

Source:
http://forums.directxtech.com/index.php?topic=5975.0

Answer (score 2):

> Finally the ID3D12CommandQueue is a first-in first-out queue, that stores the correct order of the command lists for submission to the GPU. Only when one command list has **completed execution on the GPU**, will the next command list from the queue be submitted by the driver.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/porting-from-direct3d-11-to-direct3d-12

This isn't correct. I believe DirectX12 is the same as Vulkan

> The specification states that commands start execution in-order, but complete out-of-order. Don’t get confused by this. The fact that commands start in-order is simply convenient language to make the spec language easier to write. Unless you add synchronization yourself, all commands in a queue execute out of order

I've just ran into this again. Command list **A** is not guaranteed to complete before command list **B** starts. And this creates race conditions

```
A writes    A reads
            
────────────────────
                  
      B writes     B reads
```

**Edit**: It turns out I was doing something stupid (calling `CopyTextureRegion` on two buffers) and this was casing a stall (which I could see in pix) and so my work for my next frame was started during this stall resulting in a race condition sometimes. Usually the commands for one frame complete before the next start, and if they don't you will see a gap in PIX where no work is happening for the currently view frame's timings.