# How to manage D3D12 transition resource barrier safely?

Tags: resources, barrier, direct3d12

How to manage D3D12 transition resource barrier (ex. Render Target <-> Present) safely?

If each commandlist of multiple commandlists records transition barrier from Present to Render Target in the beginning of recording, and records transition resource barrier from Render Target to Present at the end of recording, it seems it will ["limit parallelism"](https://developer.nvidia.com/dx12-dos-and-donts#barriers)

If first and last commandlists are added to only record transition resource barrier and submitted in batch, the resource transition is [not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385998/in-dx12-what-ordering-guarantees-do-multiple-executecommandlists-calls-provide).

It seems submitting a commandlist with transition resource barrier before and after workload by executecommandlists is the only way, resulting 3 executecommandlists per frame.

How do you manage this?
Anyone please help.

Comment: I believe resource barriers can only add synchronization within command lists, not between different command lists. My advice is just to copy the patterns in the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloFrameBuffering) and not to worry until you have a problem you need to debug